# POD incoming request size in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics

I have an AKS cluster where I have deployed some microservices. I have a Prometheus system connected to that and I'm able to get a lot of metrics.

One metric that is missing for me is: **The size of the requests that go in each of the microservices deployed**.

Do you know how to get that metric in the environment described above?

Comment: What's actually producing the metrics – your application itself, some middleware, a service mesh like Istio?  Can you give an example of the metrics you already have and the code that produces them?

Comment: Several sources.
- It's the framework of the application, in this case, Micronaut (https://micronaut.io/). With a simple configuration exposes Java metrics in Prometheus format
- The AKS has kubernetes metrics configured too

Comment: You need to wire something up at the framework level to provide that.  Micrometer has [a whole sub-project around metrics](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-micrometer/latest/guide/); it looks like the things it provides by default are only request/response counters.  This is independent from either running in Kubernetes or publishing specifically to Prometheus (the same answer would apply to a plain JMX publisher running on a local JVM).